# Custom authentication with service layer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an app with 3 "layers", first "datalayer", 2nd "businesslayer" and 3rd is the asp.net mvc site. And I'm trying to add forms authentication in the proper way.

Should I somehow configure it to use the business layer? That gets/adds/updates user that is a part of the authentication to be?

And in which project shall I add the user validation at?

/M

Comment: Hi @Lasse How did you end up solving this.

Comment: All in one mvc project for now. But http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/getting-started-aspdotnet-mvcservice-stack-bootstrap might be something to look into

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Authentication is something that should always happen at the application boundary, because different applications using the same Domain Model may have different authentication needs. If you ever decide to expose your Domain Model as, say, a web service, Forms Authentication is not likely to be the best authentication mechanism.

In ASP.NET MVC you can easily implement UserName/Password authentication using the default project template from Visual Studio, but once the user is authenticated, you should set [Thread.CurrentPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal.aspx).

In general, [IPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx) is the standard basis for modeling user context in .NET. For example, [HttpContext.User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx) is an IPrincipal.

In your Domain Model and Data Access modules, you can use Thread.CurrentPrincipal to implement Authorization logic. This allows you to vary Authentication and Authorization independently of each other.

If you need to work with a richer User concept in your Domain Model, you can have your [User class implement IPrincipal](http://blogs.msdn.com/ploeh/archive/2007/08/20/UserContext.aspx).

Comment: Is there someway of implementing this: http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2009/02/17/custom-authorization-with-aspnet-mvc/   into my service layer and use it from my asp.net mvc application? Or does the custom auth class need to be in same project as the mvc app?

Comment: The best way of utilizing service layer or Domain Model services from the Application/UI Layer is to use Dependency Injection (DI). However, you can't really inject a service into an attribute because it is statically wired. However, you can globally configure ASP.NET MVC FilterAttributes with DI. Here's an example showing how to do it for HandleError: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/12/01/GlobalErrorHandlingInASPNETMVC.aspx

Comment: @MarkSeemann Why should I set Thread.CurrentPrincipal once the user is authenticated?

Comment: @Rookian For you own sake, you may not need it, but many .NET frameworks tend to rely on it.