# Enterprise Architecture: MVC Identity via WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

This is more theoretical than actual application, but from my research, an enterprise architecture has many layers and they all make sense to me, but actually applying these layers is where I am having trouble.

If I implement a service layer, do I use that service layer to perform authentication and authorization via WebAPI?  If so, how does this work?  From what I have so far, I have a presentation layer that should call my service layer to call my controller service that will authenticate a user.  Does this work and is it recommended?  Maybe I am overthinking this, but if I retain authentication in my presentation layer, the code will be connecting to the database directly or through my business layer which means the application will use two methods to communicate with the database and I think that breaks the purpose of the architecture itself.

Anyone follow this and implemented this before?

**UPDATE:**
So I believe I have malformed my question.  What I am trying to do is implement the following technologies from Microsoft in an enterprise application and I seem to be having trouble decoupling them so that they work independently (separate assemblies):

- Microsoft ASP.Net MVC 5 (Razor Views)
- Microsoft Entity Framework 6 (Code First + Database Migrations)
- Microsoft ASP.Net WebAPI Services (although I have no clue when to use them)
- Microsoft ASP.Net Identity 2.0

I have a couple of issues.  The business layer in the solution should contain all of my classes that perform the work needed to be done to complete a task.  My UI layer (MVC) should call my business layer from a controller if I'm not mistaken (correct me if I'm wrong).  My business layer should communicate with my data access layer which I'm assuming should contain my DbContext (correct me if I'm wrong).  So, this layer must also include Identity (NuGet package) so my DbContext can inherit from IdentityDbContext (or does it need to?).  Now, in my UI layer (MVC), I need to allow a user to authenticate.  This is where I am stuck.  I can create a simple example, but when I try to decouple the separate layers of Identity into my separate projects (Domain, DataAccess, Business, UI) I have coders block.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom authentication with service layer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092094/custom-authentication-with-service-layer)

Comment: Not exactly.  My problem is, I come from a time when security (authentication/authorization) was home grown and we built everything from scratch.  Now we're told to use some of the new awesome things that Microsoft is releasing and the problem is that not all of the technologies work together nor are easy to implement.  In a simple HelloWorld example, they're all easy to implement.  It's when you attempt to decouple them is when you run into trouble.  I guess that's how I should have worded the question, how do I decouple Identity from the UI (MVC)?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the technologies you have listed. But in general the best practice (as far as I know) is to let the user authenticate once (pass the request securely down through all the layers) and then replace user's identity with opaque time-limited authorization token that travels wherever a whichever layer needs some authorization approval. Search for `OAuth` protocol and `Social login`. You may try to move ("flag for moderator's attention") your question to http://programmers.stackexchange.com under some of the `design` tags if you don't get acceptable answer here